# How is Bayes theorem being applied in expanding the formula of Binary Independence Model?

Tags: nlp

The [BIM formula](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-binary-independence-model-1.html) makes use of Bayes theorem. Can anyone please explain:

- How to read the probability of the form `P(R=1|x,q)`? Is it `P((R=1|x),q)` or `P(R=1|(x,q))`? Does `,` stand for AND here?
- How exactly Bayes theorem being applied to expand it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be read as the probability of R=1, given (x and y) as your second formula.
Anything after | stand for the given part.

Since:

$P(x | r=1 \wedge q) = \frac{P(x \wedge R=1 \wedge q)}{P(R=1 \wedge q)}$

$P(R=1|q) = \frac{P(R=1 \wedge q)}{P(q)}$

$P(x|q) = \frac{P(x \wedge q)}{p(q)}$

Therefore:

$$P(R=1|x,q) = \frac{P(x | R=1 \wedge q)*P(R=1|q)}{P(x|q)} =$$

$$\frac{P(x \wedge R=1 \wedge q)}{P(R=1 \wedge q)} * \frac{P(R=1 \wedge q)}{P(q)}* \frac{P(q)}{P(x \wedge q)} =$$
$$\frac{P(x \wedge R=1 \wedge q)}{P(x \wedge q)}$$